# Convert element and return contents of element using php

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I have this element in the DOM derived from a php command.

```
<a href="https://www.someurl.com/es/atencion-al-cliente">Atención al cliente</a>
```

Here is the php command that generates the element above:

```
<?php icl_link_to_element(2880);?>
```

I need to convert this element in some way so that I only end up with string 'Atención al cliente' stored in a variable so I can use this string for other purposes.

What is the best way to get this done in PHP?

Comment: Possibly by using [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Looks promising, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: Usually something like this can be solved with a regular expression (e.g. `/<a.*?>([^<]*)</a>/`), or a DOM parser or via `strip_tags` as @MarkBaker suggests. The "best way" is up to debate.

Comment: I am unable to convert the html element to a string, any idea how this can be done? See also comment below.

Comment: OK so I made a small mistake with this question because I'm trying to acquire the last part of the URL after trailing forward slash. See new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251703/converting-a-dom-element-into-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Preg_match

```
<?php

$str = '<a href="https://www.someurl.com/es/atencion-al-cliente">Atención al cliente</a>';

preg_match('/\>(.*)\</i', $str, $matches);

$wantedString = $matches[1];

echo $wantedString;

?>
```

For Wordpress edit:
I think you should get the page using `$page = icl_object_id(2880, 'page', true);` then get the title with `get_the_title($page);` or var_dump that $page to see if you can get what you want

Comment: I am unable to convert the element to a string therefore cannot carry out any strip_tags operation. I have tried converting the element using the methods (string) and strval(). Any idea?

Comment: aha I understand. You should've mentioned wordpress.

Comment: Yes you're right it is WordPress. icl_link_to_element() is a method coming from WPML translation plugin and returns that html element.

Comment: OK so I made a small mistake with this question because I'm trying to acquire the last part of the URL after trailing forward slash. See new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251703/converting-a-dom-element-into-a-string-in-php