# Converting a DOM element into a string in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I am running a Wordpress site and using WPML translation plugin. In WPML there is a method called `icl_link_to_element(2880);` that returns and generates the following element in the DOM:

```
<a href="https://www.someurl.com/es/atencion-al-cliente">Atención al cliente</a>
```

I want to convert this element to a string so that I can simply return and store the last part of the url `atencion-al-cliente`, into a unique variable.

What's the best way to get this done?

Answer to the comment below:

Two elements appear in the DOM now.

```
<a href="https://www.someurl.com/es/atencion-al-cliente">Atención al cliente</a>
```

and

```
"NULL
            "
```

Comment: show result of `var_dump (icl_link_to_element(2880));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do the following steps to get that URL

1. `$page = icl_object_id(2880, 'page', true);`
2. `$url = get_permalink($page);`

Then use `$parts = explode("/", $url)` function and get the last element of that array, you can use `array_pop()`

Comment: ok so when I echo $url, I am now getting a string value 'https://www.someurl.com/es/atencion-al-cliente'. When I echo $parts, I get 
    Array   .

Comment: you need print_r($parts) not echo

Comment: Great! Now I see I have the string I need in the 4th index of a php array. How to return this fourth index in php? Sorry I'm a bit noob in php..

Comment: you might not need to get the 4 index (hardcoded) but you need the last one, so use array_pop $wantedStr = array_pop($parts);

Comment: $parts[4] returns the 4th index anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` to get the value of href, Now get the matched value using `parse_url`, after getting just collect the path from the return array.

Now its time to get the last portion of the url, So try this below code.

```
$html = '<a href="https://www.someurl.com/es/atencion-al-cliente">Atención al cliente</a>';

preg_match('/<a href="(.+)">/', $html, $match);

$info = parse_url($match[1]);

$str = $info['path'];
$len = strlen($info['path']);

echo trim(substr($str, strrpos($str, '/'), $len), "/"); //atencion-al-cliente
```

Comment: $html = icl_link_to_element(2880);
echo $html;

This simply returns the dom element again. I need to convert the DOM element to a string first

Comment: as you said _`icl_link_to_element(2880);` that returns and generates the following element in the DOM_, store them in the `$html` variable.

Comment: No, I copied and pasted the code you provided as such but the div is still returning the full DOM element and not the part after the trailing slash..